# Verilog syntax question: z=&{x,y};

Tags: verilog

Im verilog beginner and I'm encountered some unknown syntax:

```
wire       slip_lock;
reg        fslip_lock;
wire [1:0] dslip_lock;

assign slip_lock = &{fslip_lock,dslip_lock};
```

What this code does? is it containment? or bitwise AND operand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the AND reduction of `fslip_lock` and `dslip_lock`. It's concatenating the two together (`{fslip_lock, dslip_lock}`), and then taking the AND of the resultant three bits to reduce it to a single bit, `slip_lock`. `slip_lock` will be `1` when all three bits of `fslip_lock` and `dslip_lock` are `1` and `0` otherwise.

See the SystemVerilog 2012 LRM, §11.4.9 **Reduction operators** for more information about reduction.

Answer (score 2):

The first part `{fslip_lock,dslip_lock}` concatenates ("glues back to front") the two variable. In this case fslip_lock 1 bit and dslip_lock is two bits. Thus the result is a three bit vector. It is the equivalent of:

```
wire [2:0] temp;
assign temp[2]   = fslip_lock;
assign temp[1:0] = dslip_lock;
```

The `&` is a reduction operator. It performs the operation on each bit of a following scaler.

```
assign slip_lock = &temp; // would be the equivalent of:
assign slip_lock = temp[2] & temp[1] & temp[0];
// in this case there is no temp but {fslip_lock,dslip_lock}:
assign slip_lock = fslip_lock & dslip_lock[1] & dslip_lock[0];
```

The biggest advantage of that coding style is that it will still work if the vector size changes. e.g. if dslip_lock is four bits you get:

```
assign slip_lock = fslip_lock & dslip_lock[3] & dslip_lock[2] & dslip_lock[1] & dslip_lock[0];
```